# Is It Possible To Increment A Letter, i.e A + 1 = B In Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, char, increment

I am used to doing this in C or C++, ie:

```
myChar++;
```

should increment a letter.

I am trying to do the same in Objective-C, except that I have a NSString to start off with (the NSString is always just one letter). I have tried converting the NSString to a char *, but this method is deprecated and other ways of achieving this don't seem to work.

How should I convert an NSString to a char * - or, is there a way to increment a character in objective-c without needing a char * somehow?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// Get the first character as a UTF-16 (2-byte) character:
unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:0];
// Increment as usual:
c++;
// And to turn it into a 1-character string again:
[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
```

Of course, this assumes incrementing a Unicode character makes sense, which does for ASCII-range characters but probably not for others.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I spent ages looking for something like "characterAtIndex" and just couldn't see it :)

Comment: The bottom line of code has an extra "With" though - just incase anyone else tries to copy this.

Comment: It will only work on little-endian systems. This means all Intel Macs, but no PowerPC Macs. For correct code, you could use a char and use `[string getBytes:&yourChar maxLength:1 usedLength:NULL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy range:NSMakeRange(0,1) remainingRange:NULL]`.

Comment: @Chuck: Endianess only matters for composed characters -- that is, characters composed of more than one `unichar` sequence.  It only makes sense to increment the `unichar` directly for single-unichar characters, and for this case endianess won't matter.  For other characters, converting to UTF-8 will not work either due to similar multi-byte sequences that make up UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @Daniel Dickison: You're saying byte-order doesn't affect the order of bytes within a UTF-16 character?

Comment: @Chuck: Byte-order within a UTF-16 2-byte sequence would matter if you write those bytes out to a file and then parse it.  But the unichar returned and expected by `NSString` methods are always going to be in native byte-order.  In other words the abstract numerical value represented by the unichar variable is the actual UTF-16 code, i.e. `[@"0" characterAtIndex:0] == 0x30` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

How about NSString's

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Would that work?